# Applications that use .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, product

What are your favorite applications, products, or any applications that you know of that use ***.NET or Asp.NET*** as their underlying platform? What popular companies do you know of as a .NET shop?

*This question is related to a few others that I have seen. So I've just made this one as a community wiki to see what kind of a response there is.*

Answer (score 11):

Client apps

- [Paint.net](http://getpaint.net)
- Windows Live Writer

---

Developer Tools

- [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)
- Expression Blend

---

Asp.Net apps:

- Graffiti CMS
- CommunityServver

---

Asp.Net sites:

- http://myspace.com
- http://stackoverflow.com
- http://blogs.msdn.com
- http://thedailywtf.com
- http://NewEgg.com
- http://microsoft.com
- http://dell.com
- http://match.com
- http://monster.com
- http://constco.com
- http://NHS.com
- http://HSN.com
- http://LondonStockExchange.com
- http://lego.com
- http://realtor.com

Answer (score 10):

Paint.net uses the .net framework, I believe it's written in C# as well.

Answer (score 3):

The ASP.NET web site's [*Getting Started*](http://www.asp.net/get-started/) has a "Who is using ASP.NET?" section that includes **MySpace**.com, **Dell**.com, **Match**.com, **Monster**.com, **Costco**.com, **Lego**.com, and **LondonStockExchange**.com.

Comment: Microsoft.com is on ASP.NET. And, it is no small, low trafficked website by any means. It has major load.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Media Centre

Answer (score 1):

[Toronto.com](http://www.toronto.com) was developed with asp.net - its one of the largest media sites in Toronto, Canada. you can read the [case study](http://www.microsoft.com/canada/casestudies/torontodotcom.mspx) if you like.

Answer (score 1):

[Vista Print](http://www.vistaprint.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) an IDE for .Net development.

[Xobni](http://www.xobni.com/), a popular plug-in for Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

MySpace is probably one of the biggest ASP.NET sites going around. Proves ASP.NET can handle mega load.

Comment: Myspace is built on ColdFusion.

Comment: No, it's build on ASP... at the beginning COldFusion than ASP .NET

Comment: Then why do their pages still have .cfm and fuseaction, unless they are doing some mix and match.

Comment: Extension is nothing in the web development you can change .php to .html or whatever. They have keep some .cfm to keep consistence I think

Comment: Was there ever any doubt that .Net could handle large loads?  It's one of the most efficient and scalable web frameworks around.

Comment: I think no body doubt ASP.NET can handle mega load now, but people still think if you have really big site you have to do it on UNIX because Windows can't scale.

Comment: Craig: you mean, Windows can't scale if all you know is Unix ;-)

Answer (score 0):

ATI catalyst driver control panel.

Answer (score 0):

All the programas I've created using the platform are my favorites :)

I don't really see why it matters in which platform specific applications are written as long as they perform their job in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Managment Studio and Paint.Net

Comment: Are you sure SSMS is written in .NET?

Comment: Yes.  Not all of it, but most of the UI uses .Net

Answer (score 0):

[Cray, Inc - The Supercomputer Company](http://www.cray.com/Home.aspx) - BTW. Orderd by CX1 today and its going to be sweet....

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Dynamics CRM
Microsoft Office SharePoint Server

Answer (score 0):

For me one of the more common applications that I use every day, and don't know how I could live without is Quickbookx.

It is all built on .NET as well.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised it hasn't been mentioned...

Visual Studio

Comment: I guess the reason it hasn't been mentioned is that it's not written in .Net. VS 2010 has more parts written in managed code (big pieces of the UI for example), but far from everything.